# Angular - html2canvas and jsPDF, the image from html2canvas goes wrong

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, html2canvas

My problem is with [html2canvas(1.0.0-rc.7)](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) in Angular 10 (for css, i use bootstrap), i want to do a screenshot with html2canvas and print it with [jsPDF(1.5.3)](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/tree/v1.5.3), one goes wrong and then the other goes right, have a look.

Screenshot 1 (Good):

[image]

Screenshot 2 (Bad, among more attempts):

[image]

My Code:

- HTMl:

```
<div class="m-2" id="ticket" #ticket>
    <img [src]="logo" class="rounded" style="width: 54px; height: 54px" alt="Logo" />
    <h2 class="d-inline-block text-center">{{ company.name }}</h2>
    <p class="text-center text-justify border border-dark p-2 my-2">
        {{ message }}
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Name:</strong> {{ client.name }} |
        <span *ngIf="client.domicile">
            Addres: {{ client.address }} | Telefono: {{ client.phoneNumber }}
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="!client.domicile"> Local </span>
    </p>
    <table class="table table-sm my-2">
        <thead>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let productInCart of shoppingCart">
                <td>{{ productInCart.product.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ productInCart.amount | number }}</td>
                <td>{{ productInCart.product.price | number }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot class="font-weight-bold">
            <td>Total</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ totalPrice | number }}</td>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

- Component class:

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-cash-register',
    templateUrl: './cash-register.component.html'
})
export class CashRegisterComponent {
    @ViewChild('ticket') ticket: ElementRef; // Ticket like in a cash register

    public printPDF(): void {
        html2canvas(this.ticket.nativeElement).then((canvas) => {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');

            var imgHeigth = (canvas.height * 208) / canvas.width;

            doc.addImage(imgData, 0, 0, 208, imgHeigth);

            var nameDocument: string = 'client_name';

            doc.save(nameDocument + '.pdf');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: use `var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();` and try `doc.addImage(imgData, 0, 0, width-30, height-30);`. i had the same problem.this fixed for in my case.

Comment: @hansand, nope, that's not work for me, i have 1/2 of the page in white